# Trying to remove elements in array without any import methods

Tags: java

Been trying this for a long time and have no luck. My code so far: (left some out so it's easier to read).

```
public class MyArrayList {
public String[] arrays = {};

public MyArrayList() {
    arrays = new String[5];

    }
public String get(int i) {
    return arrays[i];
}

    public boolean remove(String element) {
    String[] result = arrays;
    if (element != null) {
        int indexOf = -1;
        for (int index = 0; index < arrays.length; index++) {
            if (arrays[index].equals(element)) {
                indexOf = index;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (indexOf > -1) {
            result = new String[arrays.length -1];
            for(int index = 0; index < indexOf; index++){
                result[index]=arrays[index];
            }
            for (int index = indexOf + 1; index < arrays.length; index++) {
                result[index -1]=arrays[index];
                arrays = result;
                return true;
            }

        }
    }
    return false;
}

public class MyArrayListTest {

static MyArrayList zoo = new MyArrayList();
System.out.print("The zoo now holds " + zoo.size() + " animals: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < zoo.size(); j++) System.out.print(zoo.get(j) + " ");
    System.out.println();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Testing constructor, add(object) and size() ");
    zoo.add("Ant");
    zoo.add("Bison");
    zoo.add("Camel");
    zoo.add("Dog");
    zoo.add("Elephant");
    zoo.add("Frog");
    zoo.add("Giraffe");
    zoo.add("Horse");
    printZoo();
    System.out.println();

System.out.println("Testing remove(object) ");
    System.out.println("Elephant was " + ((zoo.remove("Elephant"))? "removed " : "not in zoo "));
    System.out.println("Zebra was " + ((zoo.remove("Zebra"))? "removed " : "not in zoo "));
    System.out.println("Horse was " + ((zoo.remove("Horse")) ? "removed " : "not in zoo "));
    System.out.println("Aardvark was " + ((zoo.remove("Aardvark"))? "removed " : "not in zoo "));
    printZoo();
    System.out.println();
```

Right now the code prints: "Aardvark Ant Antelope Bison Camel Dog Elephant Frog Giraffe Gorilla Horse Ibex"

It should remove Aardvark, Horse and Elephant and should say "Zebra is not in zoo". So That will be false in the remove method.

Thanks, all help appreciated, as I'm a very java programmer.

Also an extra bit where you have to delete at a specific index. But if i get this right it will help me with that.

Comment: I think you need to use a 'List' or a 'Set' instead of an array. Is it important that you use an Array? consider using some sort of Java Collection (like an ArrayList) and converting to and from an array as neccessary?

Comment: you cannot use == to compare content of string type in java

Comment: Your array has only size 5, how are you adding 8 elements? are you resizing the array when adding?

Comment: Where's the `add` method?

Comment: @KickButtowski Yeah I changed that and still didn't change anything.

Comment: @Anil I add extra elements using the add method.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Left it out so it's easier to see the code I need help with.

Comment: did u pay attention to other comments as well? I don't see any change in your code

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer If I posted all my code it will be too much to see.

Comment: Do you want to "shrink" the array or simply move the elements up, so that there are no gaps (allow `null` values at the end)?

Comment: I didn't ask for "all" your code, I asked for a runnable example which demonstrates your problem...

Comment: Why on earth would you implement something that has already been constructed for your own benefit.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Prefer to shrink it. I implemented in my code (length-1) to shrink it

Comment: @MalikBrahimi It's for a question from a worksheet/book.

Comment: I'm assuming you can't use `System.arrayCopy` then...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Nope, has to be done using loops.

Comment: Sadly, I must agree that you are "a very java programmer."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to shrink the array, so that there are no empty slots.

The first task you have to do is determine if the value actually exists within the array (the `indexOf` the value)

```
if (element!= null) {
    int indexOf = -1;
    for (int index = 0; index < arrays.length; index++) {
        if (arrays[index].equals(element)) {
            indexOf = index;
            break;
        }
    }
```

This does two things, it tells if the value exists in the array AND where it exists, this is useful...

With this information, you can create your new array and start moving content into it

```
if (indexOf > -1) {
    String newArray[] = new String[arrays.length - 1];
    for (int index = 0; index < indexOf; index++) {
        newArray[index] = arrays[index];
    }
    for (int index = indexOf + 1; index < arrays.length; index++) {
        newArray[index - 1] = arrays[index];
    }
    arrays = newArray;
}
```

All this does is copies the contents of `arrays` to the `newArray`, skipping over the element at `indexOf` and then assigns the result back to `arrays

Since you couldn't provide a runnable example, I had to make my own...

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] data = new String[]{
            "Ant",
            "Bison",
            "Camel",
            "Dog",
            "Elephant",
            "Frog",
            "Giraffe",
            "Horse",};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));

        data = removeFrom("Dog", data);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
        data = removeFrom("Ant", data);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
        data = removeFrom("Horse", data);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));

    }

    protected static String[] removeFrom(String element, String[] arrays) {

        String[] result = arrays;
        if (element != null) {

            // You should first determine if the value exists in the incoming array...
            int indexOf = -1;
            for (int index = 0; index < arrays.length; index++) {
                if (arrays[index].equals(element)) {
                    indexOf = index;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (indexOf > -1) {

                result = new String[arrays.length - 1];
                for (int index = 0; index < indexOf; index++) {
                    result[index] = arrays[index];
                }
                for (int index = indexOf + 1; index < arrays.length; index++) {
                    result[index - 1] = arrays[index];
                }

            }

        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

This will output

```
[Ant, Bison, Camel, Dog, Elephant, Frog, Giraffe, Horse]
[Ant, Bison, Camel, Elephant, Frog, Giraffe, Horse]
[Bison, Camel, Elephant, Frog, Giraffe, Horse]
[Bison, Camel, Elephant, Frog, Giraffe]
```

Comment: Wow very grateful, Now for my code I require it to return a boolean value. If element is not in the array it will return false. If it is, it will return true. Is the code possible for me to modify to do that?

Comment: ... I assume you can see where the element would removed, under what conditions ... I can't be that hard to change a `delete` variable to `true` when that condition branch is executed...?

Comment: Yeah sorry, just tired.

Comment: Coming up with NullPointerException errors.  But says "Elephant was removed". I removed the "return result;" because I had to replace with a boolean return

Comment: Runnable example...my code works, I have a runnable example to proof it

Comment: Okay I made some errors that I corrected. Now the boolean checker to see if the element is in the array or not works but it still does not update the array to show stuff has been removed.

Comment: Did you miss `arrays = newArray;`?

Comment: I'm confused now, is the Newarray code and the result[index] etc two different pieces of code??

Comment: Kind of.  The code snippets are suppose to resemble your code (in particular the names you choose for your variables), the runnable code is the code I used to prove the concept

Comment: Oh right well now when I do arrays = result; I get a NullPointerException error. When I leave it out, it does not update arrays. The error highlights the code if (arrays[index].equals(element)).

Comment: Another issue is that when I highlight arrays on the second line of the code it says Arrays is redundant, most likely because I left out String[] arrays in the parameter. If I add it in I will get an error because the main method code only accepts 1 parameter (requires boolean).

Comment: A runnable example, without it, I can't help you...I can't see your code or how it works - The code example works, run it. The integration into your code is the issue, but since you don't seem to want to share, there is nothing I can do to help your further

Comment: You can't return `true` from within the `for-loop`, it's not finsihed processing the remaining elements.  The same thing goes for `arrays = newArray;`, which in my example is outside of both `for-loops`...

Comment: It finally works. Thanks very much for all the help. One stage down.